# Issue with dropdown sub-menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, submenu

So I am trying to teach myself how to create and customize wordpress websites, and I have been stuck on this piece of code for 2 days now. So I'm posting here so maybe someone can help me understand what I am doing incorrectly. I started teaching myself only about a week or two ago so that's some background of my knowledge.

Well I am trying to create a navigation menu that goes in the header of a webpage just under the site-header container. The theme doesn't offer a menu location besides in the sidebar widget and the footer. I have managed to go through and add a new theme location for a custom menu through the theme files.

The issue I am having is I can't manage to style it in CSS so that the submenu drops down when you hover over the page in the top navigation menu. Here is the html and CSS I currently have for the seciton I am having trouble with:

```css
.top-menu {} 
.top-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  ;
}
.top-menu ul li {
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.top-menu ul li.current-menu-item {
  background: blue
}
.top-menu ul li:hover {
  background: red
}
.top-menu ul a {
  font: 20px Cantarell, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 175;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0
}
.top menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
}
.top menu ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 15px
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu">
  <ul id="menu-header" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/home/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/about/">About</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/recipes/">Recipes</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-51"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/category/appetizers-snacks/">Appetizers &amp; Snacks</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-52"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/category/breads/">Breads</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-53"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/category/breakfast/">Breakfast</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/contact/">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please Help!, I'm running out of hair to pull :/

PS. This is my first question I have asked on this site.

Comment: Here's a clean, simple drop-down menu I recently created for another answer. Take a look to see how it works. Hopefully, it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/hp67rvfc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The jsfiddle of Michael comment](http://jsfiddle.net/hp67rvfc/) will help you, I recommend you to use it, the only thing that I don't like it is the use of *Descendant Selectors* and the use of `opacity: 0` instead of `display: none` (I know that is for the transition but in that way you will show the menu point below it) but in general it is a good starting point.

I only want to give you some tips to help you understand it and another to improve your code.

Understanding the behavior.

You has `.top-menu ul ul {display: none;}` so your `.sub-menu` will not be displayed at all (has no effect on layout) so to show it we use :

```
.menu-item{
    position: relative; /*with respect to this element sub-menu is positioned*/
    color: #333;
}
.menu-item:hover .sub-menu{
    display: block;  /*show the menu when you hover the li.menu-item*/
}
```

At this point you should see the menu but notice that you have `.top-menu  ul { overflow: hidden;}` so the overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible including to `.sub-menu` just remove it and now you can see your `.sub-menu` but it will have a style somewhat watered because it is being affected by the styles `.top-menu  ul` , `.top-menu ul li` , etc.

So my recommendation: use the Michael example as starting point but avoid to use *Descendant Selectors* not only is this not performant but it is fragile, as changes to the HTML can easily break your CSS, it is preferable to simply create a new CSS class selector which by the way you have already in your html so use them.

Check this out it will help you to improve your code http://modernweb.com/2013/08/12/writing-better-css/?utm_source=html5weekly&utm_medium=email

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable submenu on `:hover` of parent item:

```
.top-menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
.top-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.top-menu ul li {
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.top-menu ul li.current-menu-item {
  background: blue
}
.top-menu ul li:hover {
  background: red
}
.top-menu ul a {
  font: 20px Cantarell, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 175;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0
}
.top-menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 220px;
}
.top-menu ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
.top-menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu">
  <ul id="menu-header" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/home/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/about/">About</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/recipes/">Recipes</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-51"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/category/appetizers-snacks/">Appetizers &amp; Snacks</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-52"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/category/breads/">Breads</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-53"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/category/breakfast/">Breakfast</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="http://notmymamaskitchen.com/contact/">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Between all of your tips and help, as well as some assistance from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7ayE5AtRUA), I managed to successfully get a functioning and styled dropdown menu for the website! Thank you everyone!